# Multistore slow on one URL

Tags: magento2, multistore

We have a Magento 2 multistore setup on a Dedidacted server with two stores views.

When we access one URL it has a normal load of 2-3 seconds, when accessing the other URL we have a load of +20 seconds.

www.fietsenwinkelonline.be -> normal load time
www.vliegendhert.be -> +20 seconds load time

Does anyone come accross this issue and/or has a fix for it or a nudge in the right direction?
If we need to provide more specifics please let us know.

Comment: Do you have set up correctly Magento 2 from a performance point of view ? Such as Redis + Varnish + All cache enabled + Minify/Merge/Versioning statics ?

Comment: @FranckGarnier All optimizations have been applied, server side and Backend. The weird point is that one URL loads as it should and another doesn't... (There are only two shops).

Comment: Do you know if the time spent is on Magento side ? Or on network side ? What is the difference between your two websites ? Number of products ? Custom code ?

Comment: @FranckGarnier According to our server provider it takes a while for Magento to generate the second store, initial server response is in the ms.
Both websites are identical, same products, customers, code, ... The only difference is the "view", template is identical except for the logo.

Comment: Try to remove Javascript Error first.

Comment: @FranckGarnier, this didn't caught my attention yet. It looks to refer to a SID however session id is disabled on the magento backend?

Answer (score 0):

On my chromium test, the time for both website is similar.

You just **may reach the site without cache hit for the first time**.

I advise you to activate **Javascript bundling** and **Sign Static Files** in order to avoid a tons of RequireJs HTTP request

I advise you to **set Magento in production mode**.

I advise you to fix the Javascript error :

```
(index):3700 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):3700
(anonymous) @ (index):3700
(index):3761 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):3761
(anonymous) @ (index):3761
(index):3801 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):3801
```

I advise you to setup a **Varnish** behind your Apache.

I advise you to **use PHP 7** for huge performance improvement.

I advise you to recheck that all caches are enabled.

I advice you to profile your Magento 2 to find the bottleneck, maybe custom module.

I advice you to check that you Apache can handle correctly all your requests. (Check CPU usage etc)

Comment: Minify, Merge and Javascript Bundling are already enabled & all caches are enabled.
We'll contact our server provider for  upgrading to php 7.
CPU usage is within normal range according our provider.

Varnish is something we'd like to put in as soon as everything runs as it should.

Comment: I think that Varnish + PHP 7 + Javascript Bundling will reduce you load significantly. (Javascript Bundling is not activated in my test, try to redeploy and regenerate your static files)